# Is it advisable to use grid template areas?

Tags: html, css, web-deployment, web-deployment-project

I just found out about CSS grid today and I think it is a very easy and manageable way to create responsive websites. However, I would like to know if using grids, specifically grid-template-areas, is a good way to write quality and robust code. I'm new to StackOverflow as well as web development so sorry in advance if this seems like a stupid question.

Comment: Yep. It's a fantastic way to code your layout. It has great browser support as well https://caniuse.com/#search=display%20grid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might want to consider narrowing the scope of this question by being more specific. Rest assured that CSS Grid is a fantastic layout system that can scale to any use case, and is worth studying in detail. However what you're asking for here is other people's opinions/experience about one feature of this complex layout system and it might attract low-quality answers. If you specify more detail you're interested in (simple web sites vs. complex web apps, single person development vs. large team development, etc) you'll get more helpful answers.